# Access TIKA URL using postman/curl

Tags: java, python, curl, apache-tika, netcat

I just started Tika in server mode in my Mac and I'm facing some problems. Although I am able to access the URL, the console hangs and I only get the extracted files when I cancel the request.

For example:
If I connect using curl using

```
 curl -T ./myfile.pptx http://127.0.0.1:8103/tika
```

The console hangs, and when I cancel the connection (using Ctrl+C), it returns the extracted files (but no text).

I also tried to PUT in postman, but no success. Postman is hanging

The command I used to run tika was

```
java -jar tika-app-1.16-SNAPSHOT.jar -z -t --extract-dir=/Users/israelzinc/Desktop/pictures/ --server --port 8103
```

Can anyone help me trying to solve this mystery?

P.S.: It works if I use netcat, for example:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 8103 < myfile.pptx
```

Thanks in advance,

Israel

Comment: You're not using Tika in server mode though! You need to use the Tika Server jar `tika-server-1.16.jar` not the Tika App!

Comment: Thanks @Gargravarr! It worked like a charm, but now how can I extract the images? I can easily get the text now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the post is old, but in case you need it or someone in the future will need it.

Tested with PDF file on Postman:

**URL**

```
http://localhost:9998/tika
```

**Header**

change
`Content-type: application/pdf`

**Body**
*form-data*

`key: file, value: (select your pdf file)`

Comment: It Did not work.